# How to check cellular data limit option is enabled or disabled in android 11 device?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-11, android-firmware, android-restrictions

On the android 11 device, I want to check for the "data limit" option is enabled or disabled on the device those are running Android 11. Currently, I am using [NetowrkPolicy](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkPolicy.java;l=51;drc=master;bpv=1;bpt=1), NetworkPolicyManager, NetworkTemplate classes. But those all are hidden APIs and now blocked or [restricted in targeting device android 11](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces). And code is below -

```
        if (networkPolicy.limitBytes == NetworkPolicy.LIMIT_DISABLED) {
           //currentlly data limit is not enabled on device
        } else {
            //currentlly data limit is enabled on device, so that we can calculate how much is remaining.
        }
```

I have already searched in for [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) [Not provide much information related to my task]. I am guessing this may be currently in any setting package or not sure.

**Note - I just want to check if the option is enabled or not on device those are targeting android 11.**

**Update - 1**

I am not sure how this can be useful - [KEY_DATA_LIMIT_THRESHOLD_BYTES_LONG](http://KEY_DATA_LIMIT_THRESHOLD_BYTES_LONG) (Controls the cellular data limit), this says - If the user uses more than this amount of data in their billing cycle, as defined by KEY_MONTHLY_DATA_CYCLE_DAY_INT, cellular data will be turned off by the user's phone. If the value is set to DATA_CYCLE_THRESHOLD_DISABLED, the data limit will be disabled.

Comment: For this and other questions on non-SDK hidden APIs, the key is to ask yourself what the underlying purpose of using the non-SDK hidden API is.  In your case, you want to get the user's "data limit".  Is it to avoid downloads on a slow connection?  Is it to avoid downloads if the connection is "metered"?  Then there may be a "public" alternative to that use case: see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features/5g#meteredness  : Does `NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED` (or `NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TEMPORARILY_NOT_METERED`) help?

Comment: @PeterO. Thank you for pitching in, Actually, I want to show a warning based on it, if it's enabled then will show the remaining data based on the set limit.

Comment: @PeterO. I have updated my question, I am not much sure about KEY_DATA_LIMIT_THRESHOLD_BYTES_LONG from android.telephony.CarrierConfigManager class.